# PHP MySQL Query Printing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there anyway I can see a query once it has been run and all variables have been instantiated?

e.g. I want to see the end result (String) of

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT email, password FROM users
    WHERE email = '$email' AND password = 'PASSWORD($password)'");
```

I would like to see the query string after PASSWORD($password) has been done.

Answer (score 3):

The query string doesn't change inside MySql, but you can do something like this to see what the password will look like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT PASSWORD('".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."')");
```

Comment: Also, you should [escape your strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and change the single quotes from `'PASSWORD($password)'` to `PASSWORD('$password')`

Comment: @roger: You would do whatever you did on a regular query that returns a single row with a single cell. It depends on how `$this->db->query` behaves

Comment: I'm trying to see the result of PASSWORD($password). I don't see how your solution works.

Comment: I think he means `$this->db->query("SELECT PASSWORD($password) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = 'PASSWORD($password)'"`

Comment: I think I need more context around the answer to fully understand

Comment: @brian_d: Not really. You can ask MySQL for something that doesn't come from some table. So `SELECT PASSWORD("sometext")` (without a `FROM` clause) actually returns the result from the `PASSWORD` function.

Comment: Thanks you. Please see my answer to see how you helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the string as a variable before hand.

eg)

```
$query = "SELECT email, password FROM users
    WHERE email = '$email' AND password = 'PASSWORD($password)'";
```

and then output the query with `var_dump($query)`.

```
$this->db->query($query);
```

It is better practice though to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and feed in escaped variables.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you want the statement interpreted after the PASSWORD call. I would use cambraca's answer unless their is specific functionality within codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change 
    'PASSWORD($password)'

to:

```
PASSWORD('$password')
```

This fixed my issue.